# I have bricked my android phone. Is there any way to go back?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, hardware

I just bought a new android phone running Lollipop 5.1. flashed a custom recovery (a modified recovery based on clockworkmod recovery). Then flashed a buggy custom ROM. In which many of the functions does not run properly Including many options in settings. Power off restart is not working, plus; there's no baseband installed which affects the inactivity of the SIM, wifi, Bluetooth and MicroSD card also not shown as well.

I accidentally tried to install the original clockwork mode recovery with the "Android One Toolkit". there's no original clockwork mode recovery for the phone the only one is I have flashed before.

Somehow it erased the recovery and do not installed the new recovery I was trying to install. There's no recovery anymore, when every I tries to boot into recovery by hardware buttons it never starts and brings the system to that buggy custom ROM. either there's no way to boot into bootloader or fast boot.
I have tried everything including many apps "Rom manager" "king root" for gaining access root but all are failed to do the task due to the non-availability of wifi or internet on the phone. this buggy custom ROM is not doing anything properly which can lead me to the solution, not even reboot. I have to force reboot it by pressing buttons vol+,vol- and power button. after the options came onto the screen. "vol up for recovery" vol down for factory reset options". both options bring me to that buggy custom ROM after some time.

I am stuck, is there any way to get back in the phone? I have never used the backups before flashing.

The phone is "Qmobile Z10" MTK 6753/35 I think. The custom recovery I flashed was "Clark Recovery etc", I forget the exact name, but after the name was written "A recovery based on Clockwork mode recovery". The custom ROM I currently have in my phone is "experience ROM for TT175 by EMRESAYGIN"

Comment: Have you tried the ADB?

Answer (score 0):

- Look at MTK Droid Tools and SP Flash Tool.... 
  MTK device's are virtually unbreakable ! so don't be too worried.
- Try to flash the custom recovery ( clockworkmod ) and then use the recovery for installing a new os ....
- ClockWorkMod will overwrite your old recovery when flashing a new ROM,
  So I'd suggest TWRP a.k.a TeamWin Recovery Project,
  as TWRP will keep root and recovery installed when flashing new ROM

---

If you still have trouble, Look up Unbrick any MTK Device ..

This takes you through the steps to installing a rom on any mtk device !

---

I would write more details but each rom needs specific installations !

---

!   YOU NEED AN FREE ACCOUNT ON NEEDROM.COM FOR MOST MTK ROMs !

[Flash Files For SP Flash Tool for Z10](http://www.needrom.com/download/qmobile-z10-flash-file/)

[Lollipop ROM for Z10](http://www.needrom.com/download/qmobile-z10-5-1-lollipop-file-download-enjoy/)

---

DO NOT USE FIRMWARE UPGRADE !
FIRMWARE UPGRADE WILL DESTROY IMEI NUMBER AND NV RAM ...

ONLY EVER USE DOWNLOAD MODE !

ROOT YOUR DEVICE FIRST IF IT'S POSSIBLE !

ONCE ROOTED, USE MTK DROID TOOLS ( IN LINK [MTK REPAIR FILES ])

AND BACKUP A FULL ROM ( INCLUDES NV-RAM, IMEI, SYSTEM, BOOT ETC....)

USING A MTK DROID TOOLS BACKUP IS THE ONLY SURE WAY TO RESTORE NV-RAM (IMEI NUMBER - MAC ADDRESS )

---

[MTK Repair Files

- SP Flash Tool

- MTK V-Com Drivers (generic)

- MTK Droid Tools](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3oSsgM8QdTqUW10Y2FFS25BNGM)

If you can't access recovery, you need to use
V-COM Drivers, And Pre-Boot software SP Flash tools ....

• INSTALL V-COM DRIVER FROM LINK ABOVE

• Take out the battery ( power off completely )

• Start "SP Flash Tool" and load the custom rom above by selecting the "MTxxxx_Android_scatter_emmc.txt" File

• SP Flash tool will auto load rom from scatter

• Untick preloader or Pre-Loader
( this is what you are flashing with )

• Press on [ DOWNLOAD MODE ]  NOT UPGRADE!

• NOW Plug in device and wait for download to finish and a green Tick to appear  √

- IF YOU GET ERRORS, Please tell me,
  I'll try my best to respond quickly !

---

Errors

---

"Device doesn't show anymore"
This is because you need to flash Pre-Loader again !
- Preloader needs fixing with SP MDT [SP MDT.rar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3oSsgM8QdTqaEFhRWFZT05pcHc/view?usp=drivesdk) and the correct files. (preloader from previous rom) . You can use an old version of 
SP Flash tools Like V3 [SP Flash Tool V3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3oSsgM8QdTqa0ZRTEQ4OENORXc/view?usp=drivesdk) to flash the old Backup of PRELOADER with MTK Droid Tools Hopefully ..

I have equal luck with both, If one doesn't work, the other does !

IF it still doesn't work and phone seems bricked,
You probably need to do a Firmware Upgrade, But this means you need SN Write Station and IMEI Writer to repair the IMEI, Mac adress, Bluetooth Adress etc ( On the original box or a sticker with the device )

Comment: but how can i flash a new recovery coz i dont have access to the one i just installed. coz it was erased in the attempt to install original cwm recovery?
Even i can not access to the factory reset or fastloader/bootloader by hardware buttons or either does not have acces it by adb commands. adb commands get stuck when i try to reboot the phone in fastboot or any other fastboot command.or sometime phone doesn't even detected by the adb devices. i have installed all the drivers needed before opening oem lock before installing this buggy rom or recovery. !

Comment: MTK Devices have an Extra boot for this problem   ... You need to install CDC Drivers ( V-COM)  to access the pre-boot loader... I'VE UPDATED MY ANSWER

Comment: but i have no scatter file right now. how can i get?

Comment: You should have it with the Flash Files link   ... HERE'S A STOCK ONE ! https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=45sO&id=0B_Wm2RQP1PtfcnVpaG1oVmhPLTQ

Comment: thanks. i will try and give it here if i will have a problem.that must is a sure for me :p as i am not that much of a geek :D

Comment: i have a fixed battery in my phone. so what about the step in which the battery should be t taken out?

Comment: I have fallowed the upper given steps.downloads from the given link of qmobile z10 stockrom file.loads scatter file. all the options were selected there like recovery, system,cashe, user data etc.. then i press the download button (download only was slected in the dropdown list) then i connect the phone. after installing it gives me tick mark i disconnect the phone and try to on it but it doesn't turned on by pressing the power button neither by forcing it to be in the selection of recovery or factory restore options by pressing vol up vol down n power. now what? is it hard bricked?

Comment: No it's impossible to break / brick MTK Handset's ... This usually happens straight after Flashing.. It sometimes needs to be put on charge immediately, this will initialize the boot to charge, Then it should react to power button !... MTK HANDSETS ARE STRONG FOR SOFTWARE PROBLEMS, THAT'S WHY I RECOMMEND THEM !... USING SP Flash Tools, You WILL Fix it !

Comment: now how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Now when ever i connect the phone with the pc. it doesn't recognize the phone despite all drivers have been installed already. and gives unknown device. when i opened the device manager it gives this "Unknown USB device(Device descripter request failed)". I have googled it and found some solution to this generic problem by changing the power options etc and all the solutions on the internet. but it remains the same. Is there any solution to this problem is it the hard brick? if it is how can i overcome this problem.?

Comment: You must of removed Pre-Loader !... I'll update the answer with Meta-Flash tools to reflash preloader

Comment: Yup please do it asap. As, then i have to go to my warranty if needed today.

Comment: The rom site i posted should explain that Your warranty is void upon flashing !... This is just a tutorial on how to use the links and roms to fix an already Warranty void device

Comment: Don't Worry Anyway, All MTK Device's are Un Brick able ... Using The stuff i have posted, you should recover it, Or else you can do a search on UNBRICK ANY MTK DEVICE !... They're all the same process however.. It's long and time consuming but it always works ! Its like their is always a boot before the one you broke, so you can flash it back again !

Comment: can  you please update the steps to flash the preloader or the above u are talking about?